# Append columns to empty numpy array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have to fill a text file with columns of data, showing variation of some variables in time. For each variable I want to create a column array and then concatenate them all in a single matrix to be written to the text file. I do:

```
import numpy as np
result = np.empty((0,1))    
for data in [var1 var2 var3 var4]
  results_tmp = np.empty((0,1))
  for i in len(data):
      results_tmp = np.append(results_tmp, [data[i]], axis=0)
```

how do I fill the `result` array with the `results_tmp` columns?

Comment: `np.append` just calls `np.concatenate`.  That's a compiled operation, but when done repeatedly, for one item at a time, it gets slow.  `concatenate` is better if you give it a list of items to join all at once.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have suggested doing this is very slow. It is better to construct the data with lists, then create an array:

```
result = []
for data in [var1, var2, var3, var4]:
    results_tmp = []
    for val in data:
        results_tmp.append(val)
    result.append(results_tmp)
result_array = np.array(result).T
```

Another way, if you can get the length of `var`, is to do:

```
result = np.empty((len(var1), 4))

for id1, data in enumerate([var1, var2, var3, var4]):
    for id0, val in enumerate(data):
        result[id0, id1] = val
```

But both of these methods use for loops, which should be avoided when possible.  So, an even better way is to construct the array in one operation:

```
result = np.array([var1, var2, var3, var4]).T
```

Does this give you what you want?  Note the use of `.T`, which takes the transpose of the array so that your `results_tmp` is in the columns.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. Assuming I wish to use "my" way I still don't understand if I can append columns to a np.empty array. I know how to append rows :
    
    a = np.empty((1,0))
    b = np.array([[1., 2.]])
    c = np.append(a, b, axis=0)

but I'm not able to do the same with columns!
One more thing: unfortunately my data are in the form
((x1,y1),(x2,y2),... (xn,yn))
what is the quickest way to build an array from the yi values in this tuple of pairs?

Comment: (Hey! Doesn't the four spaces indent work in replies?)

Comment: To start, you would need to initialize your `result` array to have a matching dimension in the 'other' direction from your append direction. More importantly though, insisting on doing an operation 'your' way, as opposed to an efficient or accepted way is a waste of both of our time.

Comment: Dear farenorth, thank you very much for your suggestion. I am not insisting in doing it the way I shown, I was just being... curious. Sorry for wasting your time (I am already very busy in wasting mine ;-) ).